# iron router add css animation with onBefore and onAfter actions

Tags: jquery, meteor, iron-router

How can I get animations going with iron router
A css class is added when a page is loaded
The css is from [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)
The animation shows once but navigating to other pages doesn't fire the animation again.

**router.coffee**

```
Router.map ->
  @route "page1",
    path: "/",
  @route "page2",
    path: "/page2",

animateContentOut = (pause) ->
  $('#layout').addClass 'animated fadeIn'
  console.log ('fade in')

animateContentIn = ->
  $('#layout').removeClass 'animated fadeIn'
  console.log ('fade Out')
  this.next()

Router.onAfterAction animateContentOut
Router.onBeforeAction animateContentIn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actions are called immediately, before the page is rendered.

You need to do that in the template's rendered functions instead.

Take a look here too:

http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/simple-page-transitions-with-iron-router-hooks
https://atmospherejs.com/ccorcos/transitioner

Answer (score 0):

This worked

meteor add ccorcos:transitioner

**Router.cofee**

```
Router.onBeforeAction ->
  $('#layout').css('display', 'none')
  this.next()

Router.onAfterAction ->
  $('#layout').velocity('transition.fadeIn',500)
```